# How to find the roots of several trees within one object

Tags: javascript, node.js, tree

I have a series of messages which contain unique numerical IDs, unique IDs and non-unique "in reply to" fields that reference other messages.  From this object, I'm trying to find the roots of all of the trees, as well as all of the children corresponding to those trees.  I've found it relatively easy to return an object containing a series of nodes with their corresponding children, but I'm having trouble merging them in an efficient way.  Unfortunately, this tree could be thousands of levels deep, or just one level which makes the task considerably harder.

```
let exampleTree = {
  1: {
    'ID': 'IDONE',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': undefined    
  },
  3: {
    'ID': 'IDTHREE',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': 'IDONE'
  },
  7: {
    'ID': 'IDSEVEN',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': 'IDTHREE'
  },
  8: {
    'ID': 'IDEIGHT',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': 'IDTHREE'
  }
}

// should return { 1: [3, 7, 8] }

function generateMap(tree) {
  let convert = {}
  let mapped = {}
  for (let id in tree) {
    if (typeof tree[id].IN_REPLY_TO != 'undefined') {
      if (typeof mapped[tree[id].IN_REPLY_TO] != 'undefined') {
        mapped[tree[id].IN_REPLY_TO].push(tree[id].ID)
      } else {
        mapped[tree[id].IN_REPLY_TO] = [tree[id].ID]
      }
    }
    convert[tree[id].ID] = id
  }
  let uidMapped = {}
  for (let id in mapped) {
    uidMapped[convert[id]] = mapped[id].map(function(value) { return convert[value] })
  }
  return uidMapped
}

console.log(generateMap(exampleTree))

// currently returns { 1: [3], 3: [7, 8] }
```

Hopefully, the example above makes it clear what I'm trying to accomplish.  Seven and eight are both children of three, which in turn is a child of one.  I'm trying to combine these two together.

Comment: By the way, apologies if this is a duplicate of another question.  It's annoying that I don't know most of the terminology to describe such questions which make searching for them hard.

Comment: Don't apologize, closed question serve an important purpose - they redirect from specific problem instances to their more abstract solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split this task into multiple steps and name them:

1. **Build a tree:**

   1. Associate each `message.ID` with its numerical `id`. Each `id` corresponds to a tree node.
   2. Create a mapping of parent nodes to children.
2. **Flatten the tree:**

   1. Pick the tree root whose `id` is `undefined`.
   2. For each of its children, recursively build a list of all its children's children.

Your `generateMap` computes **1.** You still need to flatten the tree, which can easily be done by a recursive function - see `findAllChildren` below.

Below is an example implementation. I tried to comment all steps and find meaningful names for each involved entity:

```js
// Find all children below a given root:
function findAllChildren(root, children) {
  let result = children[root] || [];
  for (let child of result) {
    result = result.concat(findAllChildren(child, children));
  }
  return result;
}

// Find all root messages and their children:
function findRootAndChildMessages(messages) {
  // 1. Link each id to its respective message.ID:
  let ids = {};
  for (let [id, message] of Object.entries(messages)) {
    ids[message.ID] = id;
  }
  
  // 2. Link children to parents:
  let children = {};
  for (let [id, message] of Object.entries(messages)) {
    let parent_id = ids[message.IN_REPLY_TO];
    children[parent_id] = children[parent_id] || [];
    children[parent_id].push(id);
  }
  
  // 3. Link each child to its non-undefined root:
  let result = {};
  for (let child of children[undefined]) {
    result[child] = findAllChildren(child, children);
  }
  return result;
}

// Example:
let messages = {
  1: {
    'ID': 'IDONE',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': undefined    
  },
  3: {
    'ID': 'IDTHREE',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': 'IDONE'
  },
  7: {
    'ID': 'IDSEVEN',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': 'IDTHREE'
  },
  8: {
    'ID': 'IDEIGHT',
    'IN_REPLY_TO': 'IDTHREE'
  }
}

console.log(findRootAndChildMessages(messages));
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  Fooled me for a moment that it wasn't working because I'd rewritten the object to be as simple as possible.  Thanks for showing me `Object.entries()`, never seen it used before and I was getting a tad tired of just combining `Object.keys()` with the lookup.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes seeing the same functionality implemented by different people with different styles can be inspiring. If you agree, then the codereview stack exchange might be equally interesting to you.